# app engine custom domain settings with external A record for naked domain

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine, dns, custom-domain

My project has a WordPress landing page hosted on Siteground and prototype running on Google App Engine.  I would like the naked domain `newco.com` to point to the WordPress/Siteground page and the prototype `app.newco.com` to be served by GAE.

The app also has a server of course.  To get the security working correctly, we need both server and client running on the same domain name.  I followed the [Mapping Custom Domain guide](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/mapping-custom-domains) for GAE, which has the following instructions

> - In A or AAAA records, enter @
> - In CNAME records, enter a third-level domain name. For example, enter www to map the www.example.com subdomain.

Siteground support told me that, if I want the naked domain to point to the site they are hosting, **I need to have a single A record with @ reference**. This conflicts directly with the instructions mentioned above.  Having both the A/AAAA records and the single A Siteground record all referencing @ leads to unstable results for both the app and the WordPress site.

Does anyone know how to set up the GAE custom domain while still having the naked domain name point to an external site?

Comment: You'll need to play with the CNAME records that are used for subdomains. One approach worth trying is using a wildcard *.... or the single A record to point to the external site you want, then adding CNAME records for the subdomains you want to point to GAE.

So basically you will have to do your custom config here and not follow the docs that are intended for normal usecases.

Comment: Thanks @Waelmas!  Your comment solved my problem. A single A record pointed to the external (SiteGround-hosted) site works. Then subdomain directories can be managed with CNAME with values managed by Google App Engine without A or AAA records.  Thanks!